# Why isn't TestCafe Studio assertion message appearing in report?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I created an assertion that includes a message. My expectation is that the message will appear in the report if the assertion fails, but it the message does not appear in the report when the assertion fails.

Why isn't the message I have as part of my TestCafe Studio assertion appearing in the report?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now - you have to open the report and click on the Errors link

[image]